# C++ Generic use of parent class (reference or pointer)

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class FunctionBase {
  public:
    const double operator() (double a_) const = 0;
}

class AddN : public FunctionBase {
  public:
    AddN (int n_) : FunctionBase(), _n(n_) {}
    const double operator() (double a_) const { return (a_ + n); }
  private:
    int _n;
}
```

Do I have to use `FunctionBase *` as a placeholder because of the inability of the compiler to reconstruct a `AddN` from a `FunctionBase`, or is there a way to use `FunctionBase &`?

-- EDIT --

I have a `std::map<std::string, FunctionBase *>`, and I'm curious if I'm able to use a reference instead of a pointer so I can guarantee the pointer is not NULL before I use it. I'm trying to make the code more error resistant. If I switch it to a `FunctionBase &`, the compiler complains that it cannot instantiate `AddN` from `FunctionBase &` which makes total sense, however I was hoping there was a common workaround I was just unaware of.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve a little bit better? What do you mean by "using a class as a placeholder"?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean. Placeholder for what? Could you please show how you intend to use these classes, and what is the concrete obstacle you are facing?

Comment: @Jueecy Would you please review my question, I have edited it to make it more clear. Basically I need syntactical trick or any alternatives.

Comment: @AndyProwl Would you please review my question, I have edited it to make it more clear. Basically I need syntactical trick or any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a class hierarchy suggest using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), or [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/function.html). These can hold a callable and can be stored in the `map` by value, guaranteeing the function object lifetime:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<double(double)>> functions;
```

This eliminates the need for using a class hierarchy and does not require that the functions added to the map are related in anyway, which is more flexible.

Just to point out that using a reference instead of a pointer does not guarantee that the object being referred to still exists. Dangling references are possible, just as dangling pointers are.

Comment: +1 This is an awesome new technique, but I don't have C++11 or boost available for my application.